# custom datagridview column Control will not accept a period (.)

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

I cannot get a control I found online to accept a period(.). I need to be able to enter numeric values with decimal places. I wanted to use the numericupdown control in a datagridview cell so I can use the up-down arrows for adjusting values.

This control implments the NumericUpDown control as the editing control on a datagridview column. I found it online (don't remember where), and ti was based on a similar custom datagridview column based in a calendar control.

I made a few modifications to it so I could set the maximum, minimum, decimalplaces and imcrement properties.

However, even when decimal places is set to 2 and increment is .1, when I'm typing a value the control will not accept a period.

Below is the code, which includes the classes for the column, cell, and editing control. Please help. I have no clue what the problem is.

```
 

    Public Class NumericUpDownColumn
        Inherits DataGridViewColumn

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(New NumericUpDownCell())

        End Sub

        Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
            Get
                Return MyBase.CellTemplate
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

                ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
                If Not (value Is Nothing) AndAlso _
                    Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(NumericUpDownCell)) _
                    Then
                    Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell")
                End If
                MyBase.CellTemplate = value

            End Set
        End Property
        Private _Maximum As Decimal = 100
        Private _Minimum As Decimal = 0
        Private _Increment As Decimal = 0.1
        Private _DecimalPlaces As Integer = 2

        Public Property DecimalPlaces() As Integer
            Get
                Return _DecimalPlaces
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                If _DecimalPlaces = value Then
                    Return
                End If
                _DecimalPlaces = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Maximum() As Decimal
            Get
                Return _Maximum
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
                _Maximum = value
            End Set
        End Property
         _
        Public Property Minimum() As Decimal
            Get
                Return _Minimum
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
                _Minimum = value
            End Set

        End Property
         _
        Public Property Increment() As Decimal
            Get
                Return _Increment
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
                _Increment = value
            End Set

        End Property
    End Class
```

```
 

    Public Class NumericUpDownCell
        Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

        Public Sub New()
            ' Use the short date format.
            Me.Style.Format = "N2"
        End Sub


        Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
            ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, _
            ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)

            ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, _
                dataGridViewCellStyle)

            Dim ctl As NumericUpDownEditingControl = _
                CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, NumericUpDownEditingControl)
            RemoveHandler ctl.Enter, AddressOf Me.OnNumericEnter
            AddHandler ctl.Enter, AddressOf Me.OnNumericEnter
            ctl.Maximum = CType(Me.DataGridView.Columns(Me.ColumnIndex), NumericUpDownColumn).Maximum
            ctl.Minimum = CType(Me.DataGridView.Columns(Me.ColumnIndex), NumericUpDownColumn).Minimum
            ctl.Increment = CType(Me.DataGridView.Columns(Me.ColumnIndex), NumericUpDownColumn).Increment
            ctl.DecimalPlaces = CType(Me.DataGridView.Columns(Me.ColumnIndex), NumericUpDownColumn).DecimalPlaces
            ctl.ThousandsSeparator = True
            ctl.Value = CType(Me.Value, Decimal)

        End Sub
        ''' 
        ''' Handle on enter event of numeric
        ''' 
        ''' 
        ''' 
        ''' 
        Private Sub OnNumericEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim control As NumericUpDownEditingControl = CType(sender, NumericUpDownEditingControl)
            Dim strValue As String = control.Value.ToString("N2")
            control.Select(0, strValue.Length)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
            Get
                ' Return the type of the editing contol that CalendarCell uses.
                Return GetType(NumericUpDownEditingControl)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType() As Type
            Get
                ' Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
                Return GetType(Decimal)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue() As Object
            Get
                ' Use the current date and time as the default value.
                Return 0
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

```
 

    Class NumericUpDownEditingControl
        Inherits NumericUpDown
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

        Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
        Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
        Private rowIndexNum As Integer

        Public Sub New()



        End Sub

        Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue

            Get
                Return Me.Value.ToString("N2")
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Object)
                If TypeOf value Is Decimal Then
                    Me.Value = Decimal.Parse(value)
                End If
            End Set

        End Property
         _
        Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(ByVal context _
            As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue

            Return Me.Value.ToString("N2")

        End Function

        Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As _
            DataGridViewCellStyle) _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl

            Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
            Me.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
            Me.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor

        End Sub

        Public Property EditingControlRowIndex() As Integer _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex

            Get
                Return rowIndexNum
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                rowIndexNum = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, _
            ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey

            ' Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            Select Case key And Keys.KeyCode
                'Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, _
                '    Keys.Home, Keys.End, Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
                Case Keys.Up, Keys.Down

                    Return True

                Case Else
                    Return False
            End Select

        End Function

        Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(ByVal selectAll As Boolean) _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit

            ' No preparation needs to be done.

        End Sub


        Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange() _
            As Boolean Implements _
            IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange

            Get
                Return False
            End Get

        End Property

        Public Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView

            Get
                Return dataGridViewControl
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
                dataGridViewControl = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public Property EditingControlValueChanged() As Boolean _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged

            Get
                Return valueIsChanged
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                valueIsChanged = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property EditingControlCursor() As Cursor _
            Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor

            Get
                Return MyBase.Cursor
            End Get

        End Property

        Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal eventargs As EventArgs)

            ' Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
            valueIsChanged = True
            Me.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
            MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)

        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: thats how the NumericUpDown works.  `even when decimal places is set to 2 and increment is .1` *especially* when Decimals are allowed, the user can type the decimal when using the KB rather than arrows.  It is probably a mistake to hardcode `Value.ToString("N2")` that would ignore whatever value the user set in cell style and if it *is* a non decimal, showing one in the output may be confusing

Comment: That is done 2 places. Which are you referring to? Thing is, when I typed a period it would not show in the edit control. It was as if I wasn't typing anything. I'll tried removing both occurances of that 'ToString("N2")'. The period is still not showing when I type it.

Comment: I cant reproduce that - it lets me type the decimal.  But it also doesnt save changes to the setting.  If I change decimals or min, max it uses your defaults only.  You forgot to serialize them

Comment: Yea, it's still in development. I'll add serialization to it once I figure out my period problem.

Comment: What else could be causing this, then? I tested a standard NumericUpDown on the form (It actually a complex UserControl) and it accepted the '.'. 
I would debug it but I have no idea where to start. The UserControl has 2 tabs that use different grids. The grid with this column is new to the UserControl and has bound columns. I use the custom column twice. One is bound and the other is not. 
I will create a test form with a grid using just that one column and see if that behavior goes away.

Comment: If you compare yours to the one on MSDN you'll see you are missing a lot of things (like Clone, and the prop values being read in from the column at the cell and edit control level).

Comment: I'll look at that. The test with a form, which I added to the same project, yielded the same results I had before. No period. I am using VB2005 with the 2.0 framework. But I doubt that has anything to do with it. But last time I doubted something...

Answer (score 0):

I used an old programmers trick to solve this. I just downloaded the sample code from the post [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) referenced and just added the DLL it came with to my project. This work fine and saved me a lot of trouble I wasn't looking for.